# Failed to create first library. `undefined reference to `main`

Tags: c++, makefile, .a

I am attempting to create my first linux based static library. I am following the directions from this site here.

This is the code

```
#ifndef _ADDNUMBERS_H
#define _ADDNUMBERS_H

class AddNumbers
{
        private:
        int _a;
        int _b;

        public:
        AddNumbers ();
        ~AddNumbers ();

        void setA (int a);
        void setB (int b);

        int getA () const;
        int getB () const;

        int getSum () const;

}; // AddNumbers

#endif // _ADDNUMBERS_H

~/workspace/C++/AddNumbers/src/AddNumbers.cpp

#include "AddNumbers.h"

AddNumbers::AddNumbers ()
: _a(0), _b(0)
{
}

AddNumbers::~AddNumbers ()
{
}

void AddNumbers::setA (int a)
{
        _a = a;
}

void AddNumbers::setB (int b)
{
        _b = b;
}

int AddNumbers::getA () const
{
        return _a;
}

int AddNumbers::getB () const
{
        return _b;
}

int AddNumbers::getSum () const
{
        return _a + _b;
}
```

This is the makefile I am using . The header and cpp files are next to each other

```
CC=g++

ifeq ($(DEBUG),yes)
    CXXFLAGS=-Wall -g
    LDFLAGS=-Wall -g
else
    CXXFLAGS=-Wall
    LDFLAGS=-Wall
endif

AR=ar
ARFLAGS=rcs

INC=AddNumbers.h
SRC=AddNumbers.cpp
OBJ=AddNumbers.o
OUT=libAddNumbers.a

INCLUDES= -I #./$(INCPATH)

default: $(OUT)

$(OUT): $(OBJ)       
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(OBJ)    # The @ means use the target name

%.o: %.cpp $(INC)
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean cleanall

clean:
    rm -f *.o

cleanall: clean
    rm -f $(OUT)
```

This is my output

```
admin@localhost lib$ make
g++ -Wall -I  -c AddNumbers.cpp -o AddNumbers.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.3/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [AddNumbers.o] Error 1
admin@localhost lib$
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: its a library its not suppose to have a main

Comment: For future reference, your first attempt at a new technique ought to be as simple as possible. A good first attempt at a static library is `HelloWorld.a`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your argument-less `-I` is swallowing your `-c` argument so gcc doesn't see it and use `compile-only` mode.

Either give your `-I` argument a value or get rid of it and see if that works.